# What process(es) write to TemporaryItems/.LINKS (and leaves _LOCK files inside)?

Tags: macos, filesystem, trash

Nearly every time I login to a user account on my computer (running macOS Catalina 10.15.7 with all latest updates) I seem to discover a 'Recovered files' folder in my Trash that upon closer inspection contains a `.LINKS` folder with a bunch of `_LOCK` files inside.

After a bit of digging I've tracked down the origins of these to `/.TemporaryItems/folders.<uid>/TemporaryItems/.LINKS` which seems to be a bunch of UUID named directories containing nothing but a single `_LOCK` file.

What I can't figure out is what is creating them (or more specifically is failing to clean them up). I haven't found any errors in Console.app referencing any of these file names; I was hoping there might be some error messages indicating why they're not being cleaned up.

Does anyone have any idea which process(es) create entries under this `.LINKS` directory, and why they might not be getting cleared?

I've managed to detect *when* a new file is written using `fswatch` (command line tool wrapping `fsevents`, `kqueue` etc.) but this doesn't tell me what process did it.

Comment: Recovered items is different than temporary items. Are you sure you’re focused on one specific path here? I wonder if your watching is creating the files tbh.

Comment: macOS moves files/folders leftover inside .TemporaryItems into a user's trash as Recovered files, so they're the same thing. I think there might be another location they can come from, but that's the main one; when they appear in Trash it means something didn't clean up its files properly and I'm trying to find out what.

Comment: Exactly, the move happens at boot time when stuff is cleaned up,  not when the files or filesystem were changed and the catalog updates. You’re tracking the proverbial shut the barn door after the horses escaped

Comment: @bmike: Exactly what? It DOESN'T MATTER when the files are moved into Trash, SOMETHING created them and I want to know what. I haven't the faintest clue what you think you're getting at, but if you're not interested in answering the question then why comment?

Comment: I’ll try to spell it out - I was hoping you could provide more specific detail, but maybe you need some answers to see what we can tell from your words and what we can not

Comment: I've provided as much detail as I can give; I've told you what folder I'm seeing in .TemporaryItems and what it contains, and which keeps eventually ending up in Recovered Items. What I need is to either know what is creating that structure inside .TemporaryItems, or a method for finding out what process is writing to it in real time (`lsof` hasn't caught it yet, and `fswatch` doesn't identify processes).

Answer (score 0):

Apple describes this cleanup upon restart:

- https://support.apple.com/en-mk/guide/mac-help/mchlp2919/10.15/mac/10.15

> When you restart your Mac, macOS moves these temporary files to the Trash.
> Check with the developer if you’re not sure how to handle recovered files.

It may be hard to know which app is not quitting or cleaning up, but tracing it after the restart will be fruitless. Is there any user account or other metadata that helps you uncover which app may be creating these files the OS cleans up each start?

The only Catalina system I have can not replicate your situation and the only files that are temporary are ones relating to the asset cache system (sharing pane) and they get closed properly, so they never end in trash.

```
Last login: Tue Feb 15 16:37:41 2022 from fe80::c51:da09:d876:5208%en0
root@dev ~ # ls -laR /Volumes/bitbucket/.TemporaryItems 
total 0
d-wx--x--t  3 root         wheel         96 Mar 27  2018 .
drwxrwxr-x@ 8 root         admin        256 Nov  3  2019 ..
drwx------  3 _assetcache  _assetcache   96 Mar 27  2018 folders.235

/Volumes/bitbucket/.TemporaryItems/folders.235:
total 0
drwx------  3 _assetcache  _assetcache  96 Mar 27  2018 .
d-wx--x--t  3 root         wheel        96 Mar 27  2018 ..
drwx------  2 _assetcache  _assetcache  64 Feb  8 17:03 TemporaryItems

/Volumes/bitbucket/.TemporaryItems/folders.235/TemporaryItems:
total 0
drwx------  2 _assetcache  _assetcache  64 Feb  8 17:03 .
drwx------  3 _assetcache  _assetcache  96 Mar 27  2018 ..
root@dev ~ # ls -laR /Volumes/bitbucket/.Trashes       
total 0
d-wx--x--t  3 root  wheel   96 Jun  3  2019 .
drwxrwxr-x@ 8 root  admin  256 Nov  3  2019 ..
drwx------@ 2 bmike staff   64 Nov  3  2019 501

/Volumes/bitbucket/.Trashes/501:
total 0
drwx------@ 2 bmike staff  64 Nov  3  2019 .
d-wx--x--t  3 root  wheel  96 Jun  3  2019 ..
root@dev ~ #
```

For me, bitbucket is an APFS container for files that don’t get backed up…

```
bmike@dev ~ % diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Apple_KernelCoreDump                         655.4 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.1 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     75.1 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 78.9 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                525.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      3.2 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume bitbucket               92.6 GB    disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.5 GB    disk1s6
```